# unable to load R code in package ‘SparkR’

Tags: r, sparkr

I have `sparkR` and `R` installed on my Ubuntu machine. When I try to launch `sparkR` through the terminal, I get the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
>     could not find function ".getNamespace"
>   Error: unable to load R code in package ‘SparkR’
>   During startup - Warning message:
>   package ‘SparkR’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found

Could you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

"The .getNamespace function is part of R 3.0.0. The warning message states that the package you installed was built for R 3.0, not 2.15. The package is trying to use the .getNamespace function, but does not find it as it is not part of R 2.15. You can either upgrade to R 3.0 (which seems to be a bit experimental right now) or install the R 2.xx version of the package."